# Put <h5> text on the same line as normal text

Tags: html

I'm trying to get a larger  text on the same line as normal text.

```html
<h6>Header</h6><a>&nbsp</a><a>normal text on same line</a>
```

The above line of code puts the normal text on a new line. Any ideas how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add below CSS

```css
h6{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align:baseline;
}
```

```html
<h6>Header</h6><a>&nbsp</a><a>normal text on same line</a>
```

Comment: Gah, you beat me to it! Consider adding `vertical-align:baseline;` as getting the text to line up will probably be the OP's next question! I'll delete my answer.